# How to submit a dynamically generated form to AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have an AJAX call which dynamically generates a HTML form. This form contains a number of elements including inputs, selects, textareas, checkboxes as well as    etc.

I need to write some javascript (jquery available) to get all the fields in this form and submit them to an AJAX script. I won't know how many or what fields are there (only a basic idea) as it all depends on what the user does.

Any ideas how to do this? Lets say my form name is 'ajaxform'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As everyone said, use [jQuery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). One other note is to override your form submit (if needed) via jQuery live method:

    `//Override form submit
    $("form").live("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'), // Get the action URL to send AJAX to
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(), // get all form variables
            success: function(result){
                // ... do your AJAX post result
            }
        });
    });`

Answer (score 2):

```
var string_ready_to_be_posted = $("#formId").serialize();
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: I upvoted, but @David, please notice the usage of ID! There is a difference between using "name" and "id" :)

Comment: @Site correct. Feel free to add it to an answer if you feel it is appropriate

Comment: @Genesis, added the answer as addon!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize):

```
var data = $('#ajaxform').serialize();
var action = $('#ajaxform').attr('action');
$.post(action, data, function(data) {
 ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var string_ready_to_be_posted = $('form[name="ajaxform"]').serialize();`
As addon for using NAME-selector instead of ID